# Python: How to call cgi script from another cgi script with variables (POST)

Tags: python, cgi

What I would like to do is to make 3 cgi scripts. The first prints a form. Then this form POSTS the data to the next which does the data checking making sure it is all valid. NOW here is the hard part. I basically want to make sure that if the data is invalid, I want to pass the info back to the first script so that the valid data can be kept in the form (via a POST?) and if it is valid, it executes the next script.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple web framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and use sessions?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks, I have started using Django and it seems a lot more straight forward :)